# How can I make query between 2 dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, but not working. Whats wrong?   without the line "AND 'Date' BETWEEN '2018-01-01 20:21:28' AND '2018-01-11 21:00:43'" working perfectly, but I would like make this query between dates.
Sorry for my bad english :)

```
UPDATE `players_extra` AS `e`
SET `e`.`hetimostfin` = (
    SELECT COUNT(`r`.`PlayerId`)
    FROM `records` AS `r` 
    WHERE `r`.`PlayerId` = e.`playerID` AND
          'Date' BETWEEN '2018-01-01 20:21:28' AND '2018-01-11 21:00:43'
);
```

Comment: not working how? What goes wrong? Error? Unexpected result? 'Date' looks like a string, it should be a field name with backticks ( ` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes around `'Date'` so it is treated as a string.

Drop the single quotes or use backticks:

```
    AND `Date` BETWEEN '2018-01-01 20:21:28' AND '2018-01-11 21:00:43'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have single quotes around `'DATE'`, causing MySQL to treat the field as a string literal.  But I would phrase this as an update join:

```
UPDATE players_extra e
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PlayerId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM records
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 20:21:28' AND '2018-01-11 21:00:43'
    GROUP BY PlayerId
) r
    ON e.playerId = r.PlayerId
SET e.hetimostfin = r.cnt;
```

Joining to a subquery should outperform your current approach, which uses a correlated subquery.